# How to update multiple records at once MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have 2 databases one is an old and the other is a new one which was updated and used lately, but one of my team members by mistake update some stuff in the old database and now we are trying to find a way, how to extract the that from an old db and update the records in a new one.

My 2 db are the same in structure except when I pulled the title from both tables on the IDs that were changed, I got few titles different but the rest where same.

So can someone help with this?
What I have is a list of ID from an old table that were changed about 2000 records, and what I need is an mysql script that would loop trough all of those records and update the new database content with that one.

Table structure in both tables is:

```
ID, title, content
```

So I was trying something like this:

```
UPDATE `dbA`.table SET `dbA`.content = `dbB`.contet WHERE `dbB`.`ID` BETWEEN 0 AND 2000
```

Comment: You should never try to update rows in a single table with a loop! Don't be part of the [**RBAR(Row by agonizing row)**](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/rbar--row-by-agonizing-row/)

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu so what is my alternative to now manually update 2000 records at once ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it using the following:

```
UPDATE tableA A
JOIN tableB B
    ON B.id = A.id
SET A.content = B.content
WHERE B.id BETWEEN 0 AND 2000
```

Comment: `JOIN` instead of `WHERE`, maybe?

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu I wasn't sure about the syntax of using joins in updates.

Comment: Ok then, no problem :)

Comment: @hjpotter92 your code has passed on a small scale test, now just waiting for a backup to be made on a real db and an approval from the boss to run this. If it goes well, I'll mark it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You say different databases - but are they on the same MySQL instance? If not can you expose either via the FEDERATED engine?

If either is the case you just need to load the 2000 ids into a new table and....

```
REPLACE INTO newdb.table (id, content, title)
SELECT o.id, o.content, o.title
FROM olddb.table o
INNER JOIN olddb.changed_ids c
ON o.id=c.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be a real herculean task if you try to do it manually.

You could try some tool to do that, such as [coldiff](http://rossbeyer.net/software/mysql_coldiff/)

Answer (score 0):

Have You tried something like this?

```
UPDATE `dbA`.table1 t1
JOIN `dbB`.table2 t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id
SET t1.content = t2.content
```

Comment: @vedran-semanski no I haven't. I'll have to try it out on a smaller scale first.

Comment: @vedran-semanski I get an error running your code. I get 
 `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM table2 AS tbl2 WHERE table1.ID = tbl2.ID' at line 3`